# Facebook Webhook "message" subscription field does not exist?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-webhooks

I'm trying to subscribe to private messages sent to my Facebook page.

> You can subscribe to this callback by selecting the message field when setting up your webhook.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message?locale=en_US

There is no field "message". Do they mean "messages"? The screenshot on this page does not show a "message" field either: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference?locale=en_US

When I subscribe to "messages" I don't receive any event when someone writes a private message. When I subscribe to "conversations" I receive updates, but they only contain the "thread_id" and not the content of the private message.

What do I have to do to receive the message content in an update?

Answer (score 2):

The field is called "messages", not "message". The reason why I didn't get updates after subscribing to "messages" was missing app permissions.

Comment: what permissions does the `messages` webhook need?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone facing this issue recently, the "messages" event has been moved to the "Messenger" tab in the Webhook section, NOT the "Webhook" tab in your Facebook developers app page.